# How to update virtual environment of conda based on new install in "Base"?

Tags: ubuntu, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu2.04 on WSL2. I have installed most of the packages using conda.

I created a virtual environment using conda: "PipInConda_DKU", which was the copy of base. I installed pip and then I installed open CV using pip.

Recently, I installed Pytorch in the enviornment (base). Is there a easy way that I can update the other "PipInConda_DKU"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conda CLI doesn't have a dedicated command for this, but there are a few straightforward ways of doing it. Note that `pip`-installed packages will not be reused. The best one can do for those is to constrain to the same version.

## Install Offline

#### Non-specific

The simplest thing might be just adding the `--offline` flag to the install command:

```bash
conda install -n PipInConda_DKU --offline pytorch
```

and if all the other packages match those in **base**, Conda will most likely resolve to the same version of `pytorch` you installed to **base**.

#### Specific

However, that is not guaranteed. To be more rigorous and match the exact package in **base**, you should grab that info from **base** then use it to specify the package build when installing.

For example, I have the package `git` in my **base**, and suppose I want that same build in a different environment, **foo**. I would use

```bash
$ conda list -en base '^git$'
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-64
git=2.29.1=pl5262h1f02409_0
```

to get the info, then

```bash
conda install -n foo --offline git=2.29.1=pl5262h1f02409_0
```

Or, as a one-liner, with multiple packages (`pkg1`, `pkg2`):

```bash
conda install -n foo --offline $(conda list -en base '^(pkg1|pkg2)$' | awk '$0 !~ /^#/')
```

## Update through YAML

Another option, if one simply wants everything from one environment in another, is to dump the source environment to a YAML, then use the YAML to update the target. For example, suppose **foo** and **bar** are our source and target environments, resp., then

```bash
conda env export -n foo > foo.yaml
conda env update -n bar -f foo.yaml
```

would install everything in **foo** into **bar**.

**Warning**: The `conda env update` command will mutate the environment without prompting the user to review the changes.

Comment: Thanks. I used "update through YAML" and it worked. Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I am new to Ubuntu and hence, has a limited understanding. So, I have a confusion. When I update as described in "update through YAML", does all package gets reinstalled or is it just a configuration file pointing to the same set of package?

Comment: Also, I would appreciate if you could please point me to some reading material to learn more about conda virtual environment and YAML

Comment: @GarimaSingh YAMLs are covered in the ["*Managing Environments*" section of the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). As for reinstallation: no, it will not reinstall if the identical package build is already installed.